# Generic function for case class creation with tuple does not compile

Tags: scala, generics

I shall explain my question with example as shown below.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

trait LivingBeing extends Product { def name:String; def age:Int}
case class Person (name:String, age:Int) extends LivingBeing
case class Cat(name: String, age:Int) extends LivingBeing

// usual way of creating a case class instance
val john = Person("john", 23)

// Creating a case class instance with tuples
val garfield = Cat tupled ("Garfield", 8)

// create a generic function
def createLivingBeing[T<: LivingBeing](name:String, age:Int)(implicit evidence: ClassTag[T]): T = {
  T tupled (name, age) // Does not compile; why?
}
```

How can one elegantly construct different case classes (that are of a certain trait) generically, given a type and values for its fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider type class solution

```
trait LivingBeingFactory[T <: LivingBeing] {
  def apply(name: String, age: Int): T
}

object LivingBeingFactory {
  implicit val personFactory: LivingBeingFactory[Person] =
    (name: String, age: Int) => Person(name, age)

  implicit val catFactory: LivingBeingFactory[Cat] =
    (name: String, age: Int) => Cat(name, age)
}

def createLivingBeing[T <: LivingBeing](name:String, age:Int)(implicit evidence: LivingBeingFactory[T]): T = {
  evidence(name, age)
}

createLivingBeing[Person]("Picard", 70)
// res0: Person = Person(Picard,70)

createLivingBeing[Cat]("Bob", 5)
// res1: Cat = Cat(Bob,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Creating a case class instance with tuples
val garfield = Cat tupled ("Garfield", 8)
```

...which is the equivalent of...

```
val garfield = (Cat.apply _).tupled(("Garfield", 8))
```

This, on the other hand...

```
T tupled (name, age) // Does not compile; why?
```

...produces `Error: not found: value T` because `T` is a type, not a value. `Cat` is both a type and a value. It is the type specified for the class, but it is also the companion object to the class `Cat`. All `case` classes have a companion `object` with an `apply()` method. The compiler knows the difference between them and it knows where one can be used/referenced but not the other.